# Merge Sheets of an Excel Workbook using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

I have been trying to merge sheets of an excel file using python. I was successful on appending them but merging is becoming a bit twisted for me. Any kind of help is always welcomed.

Following is the code that I tried

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os, collections, csv
from os.path import basename

f=pd.ExcelFile('E:/internship/All/A.xlsx')
n1=len(f.sheet_names)
print(n1)

data=pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name = 'Sheet1' ,header=None)
for j in range(1, int(n1)+1):
    data1 = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name = 'Sheet'+ str(j), header=None)    
    data = pd.merge(data,data1,how= 'outer')
    print(data)


data.to_excel('Final.xlsx',index=False)
```

But as this program executes, it seems to join the sheets down instead of merging, something like the picture given below:

[Result that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M6Ya.png)

[Result that my program is giving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oOk8.png)

Comment: some functions has option `axis=` to work vertical or horizontal. [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) has `on`, `right_on`, `left_on` to set column used to connect data.

Comment: you can also try `data = data.join(data1)` but it will keep some duplicated columns.

Comment: hi, @furas thanks for your help. btw are you sure about axis= being in merge?

Comment: you have link to `merge` documentation and you can see it has no `axis=` but some other function may have it and sometimes it can resolve problem. In `merge` I would use ie. `left_on="B1", right_on="B1"` to merge first and second dataframe. To merge with third dataframe it would need `left_on="E1", right_on="E1"` - so it is not so usefull in your example.

Comment: can you mention some other mention apart from join, or if i use join how can i remove the duplicate columns?